# Run-time error 1004 with Index & Match in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, runtime-error

I have some code that is attempting to do an index and match. I have defined most of the range values as variables so they can be dynamic as I want to use this with different sheets that vary in column and row size.

The Index and Match are used ranges from another workbook defined as "y" in my code. I keep getting a run-time error:

```
Run-time error ‘1004’:
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

The code I currently have is:

```
Private Sub IndexandMatch()

Dim yChanges As Worksheet, OperatorWs As Worksheet
Dim yChangesLastRow As Long, Parameters As Long, x As Long, z As Long

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\Databases\Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm", Password:="123")
Set yChanges = y.Sheets("Changes")
Set OperatorWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Operator")

Parameters = yChanges.Range("F1:CL1").Columns.Count 'Last Column in Changes Sheet

yChangesLastRow = yChanges.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Last row in Changes Sheet

yChangesLastRow = yChangesLastRow - 2

z = 6

For x = 31 To Parameters
    'On Error Resume Next
    
    OperatorWs.Range("U" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index( _
    yChanges.Range(Cells(3, z).Address(), Cells(yChangesLastRow, z).Address()), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet3.Range("H5").Value, yChanges.Range("A3:A" & yChangesLastRow), 0))
    
    z = z + 1
    
Next x

End Sub
```

**SOLUTION (Thank you to BigBen for providing me with this)**

**Here is the code:**

```
Private Sub IndexandMatch()

Dim yChanges As Worksheet, OperatorWs As Worksheet
Dim yChangesLastRow As Long, Parameters As Long, x As Long, z As Long

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\Databases\Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm", Password:="123")
Set yChanges = y.Sheets("Changes")
Set OperatorWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Operator")

Parameters = yChanges.Range("F1:CL1").Columns.Count 'Last Column in Changes Sheet

yChangesLastRow = yChanges.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Last row in Changes Sheet

yChangesLastRow = yChangesLastRow - 2

z = 6

    For x = 31 To Parameters
        
        With yChanges
        
            Dim IndexRng As Range
            Set IndexRng = .Range(.Cells(3, z), .Cells(yChangesLastRow, z))
    
            Dim MatchRng As Range
            Set MatchRng = .Range("A3:A" & yChangesLastRow)
    
        End With
               
    Dim matchNum As Variant
    matchNum = Application.Match(Sheet3.Range("H5").Value, MatchRng, 0)

                If Not IsError(matchNum) Then
    
                    OperatorWs.Range("U" & x).Value = Application.Index(IndexRng, matchNum)
                    
                Else
                
                    Exit Sub
                
                End If
            
    z = z + 1
            
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value of `yChangesLastRow` when this fails?

Comment: @BigBen The reason I do ```yChangesLastRow = yChangesLastRow - 2``` is because I am trying to count the rows excluding the first two (so for example from A3 to the last row, neglecting A1 & A2). The last row counter is there because this workbook will be updated with additional rows (so it doesn't stay constant, as in the last row won't always remain as row 31). The value that is produced by ```yChangesLastRow``` when it fails is 31 (the same as ```yChangesLastRow = yChangesLastRow - 2```)

Comment: This line is too long to be easily readable. First, split out the `yChanges.Range(Cells(3, z).Address(), Cells(yChangesLastRow, z).Address())` into its own separate line and store it in a range variable.

Comment: @BigBen if I do this, and I set it as ```Dim IndexRng as Range``` and ```Set IndexRng = yChanges.Range(Cells(3, z).Address(), Cells(yChangesLastRow, z).Address())``` will my ```z``` value still be updated and filled in with ```z=6``` and have ```z = z + 1``` applied within the ```For statement```? That's why I didn't do it in the first place because I was confused on that (hence why it's so long).

Comment: The answer is yes. The line with `Set` is executed with every iteration.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks Ben, can I do the same thing with the Match portion of the code? As in ```Dim MatchRng as Range``` and then ```Set MatchRng = Sheet3.Range("H5").Value, yChanges.Range("A3:A" & yChangesLastRow), 0)``` ? So my statement with both changes would become: ```OperatorWs.Range("U" & x).Value =Application.WorksheetFunction.Index ( IndexRng), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MatchRng)``` correct?

Comment: The answer is again yes :-) Well, except that `Sheet3.Range("H5").Value` doesn't look like it should belong there. `Set MatchRng = yChanges.Range("A3:A" & yChangesLastRow)`. Then you get `...Match(Sheet3.Range("H5").Value, MatchRng, 0)`

Comment: It seems it didn't like the commas, so I just subbed ```Set MatchRng = yChanges.Range("A3:A" & yChangesLastRow)``` and now have                              ```For x = 31 To Parameters     
    OperatorWs.Range("U" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index( _
    IndexRng, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet3.Range("H5").Value, MatchRng, 0))
    
    z = z + 1    
Next x
End Sub```

Comment: @BigBen I'm still receiving the same error :(

Comment: On the same line?

Comment: @BigBen I added the changes to the second half of my post, please let me know what you find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do too much in one line; split it into separate lines for readability:

```
With yChanges
    Dim IndexRng As Range
    Set IndexRng = .Range(.Cells(3, z), .Cells(yChangesLastRow, z))

    Dim MatchRng As Range
    Set MatchRng = .Range("A3:A" & yChangesLastRow)
End With
```

Also, I'd use `Application.Match` here, and then test if the result is an error:

```
Dim matchNum As Variant 
matchNum = Application.Match(Sheet3.Range("H5").Value, MatchRng, 0)

If Not IsError(matchNum) Then
    Dim result As Variant
    result = Application.Index(IndexRng, matchNum)

    OperatorWs.Range("U" & x).Value = result
End If
```